# Panel de dialogo en Unity_Android

Tags: unity3d

estoy intentando añadir un panel de dialogo de selección en una aplicación Android utilizando Unity. actualmente utilizo EditorUtility.DisplayDialogComplex pero al generar una APK, me salta un error diciendo que eta clase no puede usarse en Android, alguien puede decirme cómo puedo poner un dialogo de selección en Unity_Android?

un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aún no puedo comentar así que crearé una respuesta.

Has intentado usar

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog(titulo,mensaje,ok,cancelar);
```

En cada uno de los parametros va un string. Por ejemplo:

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Deseas continuar?", "El item se desintegrará", "eliminar", "cancelar");
//En sí el primer parámetro es la pregunta, el segundo es un mensaje que se
//muestra debajo de la pregunta con menor tamaño y los dos strings siguientes 
//sirven para las opciones de aceptar y cancelar respectivamente.
```

La otra opción que se me ocurre es hacer uso de la GUI y manipular manualmente los eventos mediante un script, pero espero que la primer opción te sirva.